# Two functions in the same button

Tags: powerapps

In my PowerApps app I have a button that patch all the data to my table. So far so good.

The thing is that in that same button I want to refresh all the fields too but I get the 'Expected Operator error' (image bellow)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs8XG.png)

What I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon after your Patch call before the reset call. That is why the reset call is underlined, because you haven't ended the patch call yet.

Answer (score -1):

Got it guys!
Use ';; ' in the ')'

Like this:  );;